# QTableView enable Drag & Drop columns only for specific columns

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel, qevent

So I want to prevent some columns from allowing drag & drop Events. I wasn't able to add a eventfilter to those columns. Anyone with an idea how to do that? I have an `QTableView` filled with a `QStandardItemModel` and set up for allowing drag & drop.

Comment: You could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the model an overwrite the method *Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const*.

Comment: I think that would be a good attempt but in my case I activated drag & drop for the header view of the table. So I'm not sure what I would get as a QModelIndex for the header's cells

Comment: So you drag & drop the columns to change their order? I think a small example of your code could be helpful :)